# Create an arbitrary number of plots with inputs in shiny using modules

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

Thank you very much for your time and help!

**My goal:** create an arbitrary number of plots (**ggplot2**) in shiny where each comes with a number of controls (y axis min/max, plot download button, plot, hover info for the plot). **Important**: implement it using **shiny modules**, where a module is created to build a single ui element and another module calls the single element module and loops to create an arbitrary number of ui elements (I can get it to work without using modules).

**It works** for me if the data for the plots (and the vector which is used to loop over to create each plot) are loaded globally in the app. This [global data gist](https://gist.github.com/moosik/2e2161b206ad0e46c6d9391c8bccc0e9) demonstrates my use case using iris dataset loaded globally. Here how it looks like when it works: [snapshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM5bI.png)

However, **my problem** is that I can't figure out how to write a shiny module when the data are not loaded globally. **Real life example:** I pull the data from a database, do some processing on the server side and then I want to generate the plots. **Reproducible example** using the iris dataset loaded on the server side: [server data gist](https://gist.github.com/moosik/a4985ade4347d4bedf99dbeb54323f43)

The error I get when the data are loaded on the server side (when running [server data gist](https://gist.github.com/moosik/a4985ade4347d4bedf99dbeb54323f43)):

> Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

I believe this is something to do with how I write the module for the multiple ui elements (I suspect multiplePlotsUI).

**My question:** What will be the correct way to write the module that calls another module and loops over a vector to generate an arbitrary number of ui elements (y axis controls, plot download button, plot with hover info) when the data are not loaded globally?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it'll help, but as far as I can see, your `input.data()` function is not defined in you `multiplePlots` call (`local.data <- input.data()`)

You're also calling

```
dm <- dat()
```

twice, but this `dat()` function doesn't seem to be defined

Comment: I might be doing it wrong, but input.data() and dat() are reactive objects, not functions